# Reuse jenkins pipeline or groovy script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

We have jenkins pipelines which are reused and some pipelines which use the same functions.
Now is my question: what is the right approach to reuse them.
I use a shared library but I don't know if I have to add groovy scripts or full pipelines?
The groovy scripts seem to be executed in the root instead of my jenkins  workspace which is a big issue.
How are you handling this in the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Using shared library is the right approach. You have to add just groovy scripts to your library and use them in your pipeline.

Have a look at an example, [Pipeline](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline) and the associated [library](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline-lib).